# how rearrange data in a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a data as:

```
data=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8];
```

I need a new data matrix (4 x 8),like this:

```
new_data =[ 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0
            0 0 3 4 0 0 0 0
            0 0 0 0 5 6 0 0
            0 0 0 0 0 0 7 8 ]
```

How to do it using a FOR loop ? Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use a for loop

```
data = 1:8;

newdata = [reshape(data,2,4); zeros(8,4)];
newdata = reshape(newdata(1:32), 8, 4)';
```

Here's a solution that does use a loop, if you want it

```
clear('newdata');

for ii = 1:4
  index = 2*(ii-1)+1:2*ii;
  newdata(ii,index) = data(index);
end
```